# Calculate number of possible combinations to represent n cent

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

The question is -

Given an infinite number of quarters(25 cents), dimes (10 cents), nickels (5 cents) and pennies (1cent), write code to calculate the number of ways of representing n cents.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Or if it's even correct? It's written in Java.

```
Int[] data = new int[n];

Public int numWays(int n) {

If (n == 0 ) {
    Return 0;
}

If (n==1) {
    Return 1;
}

If (data[n] != -1) {
    Return data[n];
}

Return Data[n] = numWays(n-25) + numWays(n-10) + numWays(n-5) +numWay(n-1);
}
```

Comment: data hasn't been populated before you return one of its elements

Comment: If n is 0 there is 1 way, if n is less than 0 there are 0 ways, otherwise recurse.

Comment: In addition to Paul's answer - If and Return should be if and return. Also, you have data at the top and Data at the bottom. Use data (as it's naming conventions) and stick with it.

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking here. Does your code not compile? Does it run, but fail? Does it run and create a result, and you're asking if the result is correct?  Just asking us "what's wrong with my code" without giving us some indication of the problem you're having is not going to receive positive responses.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code:

- `Int[] data = new int[n];`
  `Int` is not a defined type in java (guess this is just a typo), `n` is not defined in scope (i guess you're referring to the input for `numWays`)
- `Public` should be `public`
- an `int[]` is initialised with 0 as default-value, not -1

Apart from that: why the array? that's horribly inefficient for memory and won't work in the way you suppose it to work. Either replace this part of the code with a `HashMap`, or - since you're obviously a beginner - leave it away completely for the sake of simplicity. And you should add a range-check. So far you might generate a method-call with `n < 0`, which will end with a `StackoverflowException`.

Comment: If you are going to call the function once, an array does not use more memory than a HashMap, and I would expect it to use less. A HashMap is easier to reuse. I recommend that a beginner do the array correctly rather than eliminating it or replacing it with a HashMap.